# array of array/массив массивов

Tags: c#

У меня есть массив

```
Para[] Day = new Para[8];
```

из структуры:

```
struct Para                        //Описываем структуру с полями:
{
    public int para_number;        //Номер пары
    public string para_name;       //Название предмета
    public int room_number;        //Номер кабинета
    public string teacher_name;    //Имя преподавателя 
}
```

ещё есть массив

```
Day[] Week = new Day[5];
```

Как мне получить и задать значения элементов?

Для `Day[i].para_name;` это понятно.  Но для `Week[i].Day[j].para_name` это не работает, ровно как и для `Week[i][j]`.

Comment: Во-первых, многострочный код нужно оформлять отступами в четыре пробела или нажатием кнопки `{}`, а не одинарными кавычками. Во-вторых, вам стоит предоставить код `Day`, иначе нельзя сказать, в чём проблема.

Comment: @AifanF, правка уже отправлена.

Comment: Что означает «это не работает»? Ошибка при компиляции или во время выполнения? Какой текст ошибки?

Comment: А `Day[] Week = new Day[5];` у вас не дает ошибку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не правильно объявили массив `Week`. Так действительно не будет работать потому, что `Day` - это не тип данных, а имя переменной, если основываться на приведенном вами примере.

Исправить можно следующим образом:

Использовать jagged array (массив массивов)

```
Para[][] Week = new Para[5][];
for(int i = 0; i< Week.Length; i++)
{
    Week[i] = new Para[8];
}

Week[0][0] = new Para(...);
```

Использовать двумерный массив

```
Para[,] Week = new Para[5, 8];

Week[0, 0] = new Para(...);
```

Явно определить класс или структуру `Day` и использовать ваш вариант